# How unsafe is EnableUnsafeClientMailRules?

Tags: outlook

To implement some automatic rules that run scripts in Outlook, you now (following the [KB3191883](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191883/may-2-2017-update-for-outlook-2016-kb3191883) update in 2017) have to [set the `EnableUnsafeClientMailRules`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3191893/how-to-control-the-rule-actions-to-start-an-application-or-run-a-macro) in the registry.

A lot of online tutorials mention to do this, but do not describe the impact.

How unsafe is it?